# how to vary the space between the object and mirrored object

Tags: modeling, mirror

[image]

is their a way to space the right side of subjects face (mirrored object) further away from the left side of subjects face so that the eyes match up better to the photo?

added mirror of circle with no clipping and this is what I end up with.

Comment: In [object mode] move the [origin] of your eye mesh to center of face image.  In [edit mode] move the eye mesh to match the eyes of image.  State in your question whether or not you have understanding of [object mode] versus [edit mode] and [origin]

Comment: Thank you I think I got it figured out. I mirrored the object in object mode, then went to edit mode, sized the circle to match the eye size then seperated them from center. that moved them to the respective areas over both eyes, respectively. then went from there, and work off of that. @atomicbezierslinger

Comment: If you have arrived at a solution ... please place a BSE answer for your own question and mark it as an answer, so that others do not attempt to answer your question again.

Comment: that is like a 2 to 3 day proccess .. rules rules rules ..

Comment: Thank you I think I got it figured out. I mirrored the object in object mode, then went to edit mode, sized the circle to match the eye size then seperated them from center. that moved them to the respective areas over both eyes, respectively. then went from there, and work off of

Comment: You are correct. Whenever you want to mirror and you want to increase distance, you need to move the vertices in edit mode further away from the object's origin.